# Url.Action returning empty string in some environments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I have a Sitecore site and on 2 of my CD servers, `Url.Action` returns an empty string.  This works locally and on 9 other servers ranging from dev to prod, CD and CM.

Deployment automation ensures that the exact same `web.config` is deployed to all environments; ditto for all other configs.

My controller inherits from `SitecoreController` properly.  This is not isolated to a certain controller or action, this happens with all controllers and actions.

What would make `Url.Action` return an empty string in one environment and not others, with identical code?

Comment: You say sometimes, but in what cases/situations do you refer to as sometimes. This question is rather open ended at the moment.

Comment: On 2 of my CD servers.  They are a scripted deploy sitecore with this script run to configure it as CD https://gist.github.com/thesoftwarejedi/e603bcf8f412d030ecab2ac776f64e19.  That is the main different, besides switchmastertoweb

Comment: May I want you to tell me what's inside `@Html.Raw(Url.Action())` please? Why you don't use sth useful like https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC ?

Answer (score 7):

> What would make Url.Action return an empty string sometimes?

Specifically, route values that are derived from the current request.

### Explanation

The `Url.Action` method is driven by the `UrlHelper`, which in turn is driven by routes. It uses *route values* to determine which route to use to build the URL. The routing framework attempts to match each route against the route values in the order they are registered until a match is found. If the routing framework reaches the end of the routing table and there is still no match, it returns an empty string (because there is no other reasonable default behavior).

On the other hand, if you call `Url.Action` and pass a route name, this narrows the possible matches to only 1 specific route (the named one). But the route values still need to match that route or you get the default empty string.

In general, all route values must match, but there are a couple of things that may make the behavior quirky:

1. Route values can be made optional. This means that the route value doesn't need to be present in order for the route to match.
2. If a route value is not supplied in the call to `Url.Action`, it may be supplied automatically **if it exists in the current request**.

This second quirk means that if `Url.Action` is put on a shared view and one request contains a route value to make it match a route, and another request doesn't contain that route value, in the latter case the URL may match another route or it may be an empty string.

### Example

Say the routing configuration is setup like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AboutWith4RouteValues",
            url: "test/home/about/{foo}/{bar}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ContactWith4RouteValues",
            url: "test/home/contact/{foo}/{bar}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact", bar = UrlParameter.Optional });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Home",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
    }
}
```

Also, let's say there is a link on the `_Layout.cshtml` page:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("About", "Home")'>About</a>
```

If you go to the home page in the browser (`/`), the resulting link URL will be:

```
<a>About</a>
```

This is because `foo` and `bar` are not present in the route values of the request so it doesn't match any of the registered routes.

> Actually, `Url.Action` returns an empty string, but Razor optimizes away the empty `href=''` attribute.

On the other hand, if you put this URL in the browser:

```
/test/home/contact/arg1/arg2
```

The link URL is generated as:

```
<a href='/test/home/about/arg1/arg2'>About</a>
```

This is because both `{foo}` (with value `arg1`) and `{bar}` (with value `arg2`) are available in the current request. Note that the incoming request matches the `ContactWith4RouteValues` route, but when the link URL is generated it uses the `AboutWith4RouteValues` route. Since both `foo` and `bar` are present in the request, they are carried over to the generation of the URL.

Now, if the URL in the browser is changed to:

```
/test/home/contact/arg1
```

It still matches the `ContactWith4RouteValues` route because the last value is optional. However, the URL that is generated is now:

```
<a>About</a>
```

This is because `foo` has a value in the request, but `bar` has no value, the `Url.Action` generation request does not match `AboutWith4RouteValues` because `bar` is a required value in order to make it match. And since it also doesn't match the `Home` route, we have reached the end of the route table and the only logical thing to return is empty string.

### Workaround

The simplest workaround to avoid these quirks of the current request is to **manually specify the route values** when calling `Url.Action` or other `UrlHelper` based methods (such as `ActionLink`, `RedirectToRoute`, etc).

```
<a href='@Url.Action("About", "Home", new { foo = Model.Foo, bar = Model.Bar })'>About</a>
```

This ensures those values are always present when building the URL even if they don't happen to be part of the current request.

Comment: What would make Url.Action return an empty string in one environment and not others, *with identical code*?

Comment: According to [this page](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Mvc-Routing) there is a `MvcRouting.config` file for SiteCore. Is it the same between enviornments?

Comment: Also, are you looking at the *exact same URL* on both environments? As mentioned, the URL of the current request can affect the URL that is generated.

Comment: Yes, exact same url.  You may be onto something with configs.  Testing not doing some of these deletes now.

Comment: Sorry, just seeing this - This remained unsolved when I left the company last year just weeks after this headache. It was related to Sitecore and like so many other things in that world it was likely a Sitecore specific bug deep in the pipeline hierarchy. I do not miss Sitecore.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue and for me the issue had to do with Case-Sensitivity in my Routing.
Deploying the same site to two different Applications on the same IIS Web Server.
I used the same web-config and same VS Web Publish Settings.
Yet, my `Url.Action` was returning blanks (empty-strings) in Prod, but not in Dev.
After reviewing the code, something caught my eye.

I have an Area called `WorkBench` (upper-case "`B`").
In a few places (where `Url.Action` returned blank), I was passing in `Workbench` (lower-case "`b`").
I have some fancy logic in my `RouteConfig.cs` and Area Registration (i.e. `WorkBenchAreaRegistration.cs`).
In those files, I had Conditional Logic to determine what Environment the Application was running in.
I use the same Project to share code, but only want some Areas accessible in different Environments.
Even though Prod and Dev are different Environments, to debug this issue,
    I altered them so they would temporarily appear the same.

The issue was fixed once I capitalized the "`b`" to "`B`" everywhere.
I still do not know why it would work on my local machine and in Dev, but *not* in Prod.
It should have behaved the same way in both Environments.
Again, same server, same publish, same web.config, same iis config, same application code, etc...
Sorry I don't have an explanation for this, but at least this is a possible fix you could try.

Hope this helps someone out there.

Update 02/08/2019: I had this problem again with a different link and for this one I realized I had an option set to access all Actions within an Area when one of my Debug variables was set to true, or when running in Prod.  I removed this conditional logic in my AreaRegistration.cs file and it fixed the problem when running in a Staging envrionment.

The Lesson Learned here is that anytime you see a blank Href, you gotta check those Route Configs.